# Оптимизация работы с QAxObject Word.Application

Tags: qt, оптимизация, com, ms-word, activex

При переборе файлов более чем несколько страниц(я тестил 75 страниц мелкого текста, по логу там 33к слов) за минуту перебирается 2к слов, далее после где-то 5к скорость практически по экспоненте уменьшается и после 8к ну практически 5 слов в секунду, а после 10к 1-2 слова в секунду, и файл в 33к слов у меня перебирался 2 часа 20 минут.
Код таков:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QAxObject>
#include <QColor>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QFile>

#define _ qDebug() <<

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QAxObject *m_word = new QAxObject("Word.Application", 0);
//    m_word->setProperty("Visible", true);
    QAxObject *documents = m_word->querySubObject("Documents");
    QAxObject *newDocument = documents->querySubObject("Add(QVariant)", QVariant("D:\\test.docx"));

    QAxObject *words = newDocument->querySubObject("Words");
    int countWord = words->property("Count").toInt();

    _ countWord;
    for (int a = 1; a <= countWord; a++)
    {
        QAxObject *word = words->querySubObject("Item(int)", a)->querySubObject("FormattedText");
        QAxObject *font = word->querySubObject("Font");

        _ a;

        if (word->property("Text").toString() == "\r")
            _ "";

        delete font;
        delete word;
    }

    m_word->dynamicCall("Quit()");

    delete words;
    delete newDocument;
    delete documents;
    delete m_word;

    return 0;


    return app.exec();
}
```

В целом в коде простой цикл, других вариантов перебора я не знаю, собственно вопрос в оптимизации такого вот перебора.

Answer (score 0):

Такой код попробуйте:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAxObject>
#include <QColor>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QFile>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QAxObject *m_word = new QAxObject("Word.Application", 0);
    //m_word->setProperty("Visible", true);
    QAxObject *documents = m_word->querySubObject("Documents");
    QAxObject *newDocument = documents->querySubObject("Add(QVariant)", QVariant("D:\\test.docx"));

    QAxObject *word, *font;
    QAxObject *words = newDocument->querySubObject("Words");
    int countWord = words->property("Count").toInt()
    qDebug() << countWord;
    for (int a = 1; a <= countWord; a++) {
        word = words->querySubObject("Item(int)", a)->querySubObject("FormattedText");
        font = word->querySubObject("Font");
        qDebug() << a;
        if (word->property("Text").toString() == "\r")
           qDebug() << "";

    }

    delete font;
    delete word;

    m_word->dynamicCall("Quit()");

    delete words;
    delete newDocument;
    delete documents;
    delete m_word;

    return 0;
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Изменений в скорости парсинга - 0.